# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, syntax-error

My following code run well without php when I put the array values in script variable. But in php it console.log `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Please help me to find my mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<?php
    $availableName = array("ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell"); 
    $availableName = json_encode($availableName);
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    echo "  $(function() {";
    echo "    var allTags =" . $availableName;
    echo "    $( \"#tags\" ).autocomplete({";
    echo "      source: allTags";
    echo "    }); }); </script>"; 
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. Browser JavaScript is a client-side one. They don't interact at all. If you have a JavaScript syntax error you should at least have a look at *View Source* and see what your JavaScript code looks like.

Comment: \"text/javascript\" this is the problem. Instead of scaping replace with single cuotes and it works

Answer (score 1):

I think it is happen because of this `$(function()` and `$( \"#tags\" )`

php will read it as variable then you got error.

Example :

```
$abc = "test";
echo "$abc123"; //test123
```

to fix it, change from double quote `"` to single quote `'`

Answer (score 1):

The $ should not harm in this case. If I got you right the problem shows up when executing the output in the browser (so a JavaScript error, instead of a PHP error).

You are putting the JavaScript all in one line, so you are required to add a semicolon to the end (after "Haskel"])

Instead of

```php
echo "    var allTags =" . $availableName;
```

Try this:

```php
echo "    var allTags =" . $availableName . ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be related to many of the quotes being escaped improperly.  Alternatively, I would probably code it as follows, which cuts down on the PHP to javascript translation mess which provides the added benefit of looking more compact, readable, and concise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var allTags = <?php echo json_encode(array("ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell")); ?>;
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({'source': allTags});
    });
</script>
```

You'll also notice that I placed quotes around the object key in the `autocomplete` options object.  This may be an antiquated practice with newer browsers; however, older browsers needed object keys to be quoted in order to parse the json object properly.  I find it to still be a good practice because it helps avoid confusing keys with variables at quick glances.

Comment: I just tested this in PHPFiddle and it seems to work without any errors.